# Delegate to Azure DNS Zone broke the site

Tags: azure, dns

I was attempting to do something else and obviously did not know that the "Delegate to Azure DNS Zone" would break my site.  Because after I clicked the button, my site no longer can be displayed.  I immediately removed this but it is  still unable to be displayed.  Can anyone fill me in on what I need to do to make this work again?  Happy to provide more information just not sure what else you may need to help.  I purchased the domain through Azure about a year ago.

Comment: Where did you press the button? It's a bit hard to say what happened though, if the DNS zone is created properly in Azure DNS and the nameserver records point to it correctly, the domains should resolve. Obviously in your case something was not setup right or was not yet complete. DNS propagation can take a while after all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you bought the domain one year ago and your domain is hosted by GoDaddy(your domain registrar, where you bought domain through Azure portal). It means requests to your site is resolved by name servers provided by GoDaddy after then.

When you use "Delegate to Azure DNS", those name servers will be replaced by ones provided by Azure. (If you didn't do any similar settings except clicking one button, that means operations are finished through one click.)

So your site is lost for the moment due to the change of name servers. As @juunas said, DNS propagation may take some time(Up to 48h but usually faster).

You may also need to check, whether your DNS record in DNS Zones and your Hostname bindings are changed or removed by the delegation operation.

Hope it helps.
If the problem can't be solved, you can show us:

- Where is the button on your site
- How do you remove this settings
- DNS records and hostname bindings